# Не( )обеспеченные граждане — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

**Материально не обеспеченные граждане** пишется раздельно или слитно?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ исправлен.

**НЕОБЕСПЕЧЕННЫЙ,**  1. Не имеющий достаточных средств к существованию. Н-ые люди. Артисты - народ н. Н-ая старость. 2. Финанс. Не имеющий денежного обеспечения. Н-ое денежное обязательство. Н. счёт.

Необеспеченный человек, материально необеспеченный человек, финансово необеспеченный закон — **всё это термины со слитным написанием (прилагательное + зависимое слово)**, например:  "Между тем материально необеспеченный и социально незащищенный субъект, как правило, не принимает существующие правовые нормы..."

Необеспеченных  граждан называют  также малоимущими  и малообеспеченными.

Сравнить:  граждане, **не обеспеченным жильем**  — раздельное написание **причастия** при наличии зависимого слова.

Comment: Что насчёт https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9 ?

Comment: м.б. тут слово "материально" лишнее?